# Using List-Unsubscribe headers in emails in Postfix Mail Sever

Tags: 22.04, email, postfix

Please guide me to to add List-Unsubscribe header in email in postfix mail server. I tried doing that in linux server. But the List-Unsubscribe header is not showing when I sent mails. When I restarted the postfix server after adding, no change in the header.

I added the following `in/etc/postfix/main.cf` : `header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/list_unsub_header`

Then I created a `list_unsub_header` file in `/etc/postfix/` and added the following: `/^Content-Transfer-Encoding:/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: mailto:<sender-email-address>?subject=unsubscribe>"`

After that, I restarted the postfix service. Still no change took place.

My Ubuntu version is 22.04.1

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to get the unsubscribe-header working in Postfix using

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/list_unsub_header to main.cf
```

and

```
/^Content-Type:/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: <mailto:unsubscribe@mydomain.com> to /etc/postfix/list_unsub_header
```

[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiftY.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration looks right in general, but it could be that the mail, which you are sending, does not contain a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header. Thus, the regex won't match and no `List-Unsubscribe` header would be added.

You can fix this by matching against the `Content-Type` header instead, which should be included in almost all mails. Also the content of the `List-Unsubscribe` header needs some fixing, since it is not a valid `mailto:` URL right now.

A working example of */etc/postfix/list_unsub_header* could look like this:

```
/^Content-Type:/i PREPEND List-Unsubscribe: mailto:user@example.com?subject=unsubscribe
```

Don't forget to replace the email-address in the line with your own ;)